# Simulate touch on bottom left of screen - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am running some tests and need to simulate a touch on the bottom left of the screen.  How do I achieve this through Swift 3?

Comment: Did you try to search "ios ui test" on Google?

Comment: Btw, in my opinion, the best way is to use UI or Unit test in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UIView` at desired position (bottom left in your screen!) and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it and make `UserInteractionEnable` for that `UIView`. You can keep `view's color transparent` if you want to not display it. Like wise you can add `UIButton` also with clear color and can handle it's action method also.

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question.